# Laravel set config values using middlware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

In my laravel package, i want to set new config values using Global Middlware

So, i register middleware using service provider

```
public function boot()
    {
        Route::middlewareGroup('mypackagename', config('mypackagename.middleware', []));
        .....
```

Then i set the middleware class in the package config file like this:

```
'middleware' => [
        'web',
        qoraiche\mypackagename\Http\Middleware\setConfigs::class,
    ],
```

setConfigs Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // --
        config(['mail.from.name' => 'New Name']);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I do tests and the middleware registered correctly, but I still can't set config values in runtime.

the only thing that works for me is when i set config values in the service provider boot method.

```
public function boot()
    {

     config(['mail.from.name' => 'New Name']);

     ....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5.6+,6,7,8,9 and 10 I can confirm, if you want to set config values via middleware, you need to use the *Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config* façade and the set method as in:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

Config::set('app.name','new value');
```

The helper method won't work in a middleware, but in most other places:

```php
config(['app.name' => 'new value'])
```

Comment: Facades\Config and use Cookie? Typo?

Comment: @Ratto no not a typo, normal PHP syntax, you could also write it as following:

`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::set('app.name','new value');`

Comment: yes but config and cookie are different things

Comment: @Ratto damn, the way eyes can just autocorrect while reading, thanks, fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Middleware are executed after service providers and config loads. This means that when the Mail stack is inizialized, it takes the "old" config values.

You should do something like this, after you set the config in the middleware, given that you are working with the `MailServiceProvider`.

```
(new Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider(app()))->register();
```

Anyway it's a bad practice to change the config values in the middleware (as you can see, it doesn't work all the time), you have to do that in service providers.

This also because Middleware are not executed in non-http scenarios (job queues, artisan commands, scheduled tasks...)

Anyway

Comment: But I can't use Models and DB in service providers, i'm trying to get settings from DB and set them in the config. @leonardo-rossi

Comment: Why you say you can't use Models and DB in service providers? You can use your models in `boot()` and the `DB` facade also in `register()`

Comment: It's a bad practice, and this will affect my package reputation, what would be the best why to set config values, edit config files directly (programmatically)?

Comment: IMHO using DB facade in a service provider is not a bad practice at all. 
Use your own config file and publish it so the user can configure that. Without much context is hard to give you an answer.